# library to visualize generated schedule

Tags: python, visualization, schedule

Which python lib/tools you recommend to visualize generated schedule (time shifts vs. weekdays and certain hours + names of the workers who should take the shift and type of the tasks are scheduled)?

Shift length, hours when each task is scheduled, task name and the worker's names are generated by other scripts.

Currently I did an ugly prototype, which use a sns heatmap ( I color cells of one shift into one color, and add customized text annotation), but it looks as  ascii art. I believe there mush be a better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Off the top of my head I think SVG files wouldn't be a bad choice, there are probably libraries that exists that could help make an  chart in that medium.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a web browser interface there are a number of calendars built in js. Fullcalendar is free and fantastic. You can store your schedules as json objects and load them that way.